# How to get information about a User-Defined Type?

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, user-defined-types

In simplicity, PL/SQL generally follow the following:

```
DECLARE 
     Variable declaration
BEGIN 
     Program Execution 
EXCEPTION 
     Exception handling
END;
```

I am quite new to PL/SQL and i am looking at the variable declaration section where i would like to find out more information on `SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST`.

Is there a table i may look up to check on information on SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST, such as checking out table column information from all_tab_cols view?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DISCOUNTS
(
  v_have_list SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST
)
IS
  QUERY VARCHAR(5000);
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Oracle database has an extensive data dictionary (what some other DBMS products call the INFORMATION SCHEMA).  You can find all the views [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_part.htm#i125539).  Alas, the revised ToC structure makes it harder to find something in the 11g documentation unless you already know what you're looking for,  so [use the index instead](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/index.htm). 8-)

Anyway, the views you need to query are [ALL_TYPES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2112.htm#sthref1504) and [ALL_TYPE_ATTRS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2109.htm#sthref1498).

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be user defined collection type. You can find some information about it querying [all_types/user_types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2112.htm) view:

```
select * from user_types where type_name = 'SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST'
```

The definition of the type can be found for example by querying [all_source/user_source](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm) view:

```
select text from user_source where name = 'SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST' order by line
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get DDL:

```
SELECT dbms_log.substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST'), 32767,1) 
FROM DUAL;
```

see: http://www.myoracleguide.com/s/gen_schema.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found something:

```
select * 
from all_objects
where object_name like 'SALES%';
```